# Django logging format for Logstash

Tags: python, django, logstash

I'm trying to configure my django application to write logs in a format which is easy for Logstash to consume. (Inspired by the Winston logging package for Node)

Logstash expects a JSON object with the log message in a key "@message" and a timestamp "@timestamp". Does anyone know how to format the Django logs like that?

So far I have something similar to what is in the django docs.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': './logs/app.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

That makes logs like this:

```
WARNING 2015-05-22 21:20:19,082 base 3360 4588670976 Not Found: /register/fwq
```

Anyone have suggestions on how to JSON encode the message in the Logstash format?

---

#### Using Python 2.7.9, Django 1.8, and Logstash 1.5

Comment: i guess you might have better experience by using a grok filter in the logstash agent

Comment: I know I *could* do it that way. But I'm trying to make a generic package anyone can use for Django, like the https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-logstash-file is for node.

Comment: Only ancient versions of Logstash use `@message`. Nowadays it's plain `message`. None of the stock Python formatters produce JSON logs but there are a number of them on GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to catch Django logs with the following:

pattern:

```
DJANGO_LOGLEVEL (DEBUG|INFO|ERROR|WARNING|CRITICAL)
DJANGO_LOG %{DJANGO_LOGLEVEL:log_level}\s+%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\s+%{TZ:log_tz}\s+%{NOTSPACE:logger}\s+%{WORD:module}\s+%{POSINT:proc_id}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:content}
```

filter:

```
filter {
     if [type] == "django" {
        grok {
             match => ["message", "%{DJANGO_LOG}" ]
        }

        date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
            target => "@timestamp"
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This [1] package provides a solution, but instead of writing to a file with formatters, it directly provides a handler to write to logstash.

Hope this helps.

[1] https://github.com/vklochan/python-logstash