# Retrieve extra fields in Kibana

Tags: python, django, logstash, kibana

I'm loggin from my Django app to a Logstash handler as so :

```
logging.log(logging.INFO, 'Account balance', {'account': a.name, 'platform': a.platform, 'currency': currency, 'amount': balance['result']['currency']})
```

I would like to aggregate and play with this data from Kibana. I've a lot of other log formats and would like to have a way to display and visualize this data without explicitly writing a filter for each possibility.

Is there a versatile way to get those 'fields' value and get them in Kibana?

Comment: You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408268/django-logging-format-for-logstash) to know how to process Django logs using Logstash.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'm already using python-logstash which is doing the formatting on its end. I would like to know how to catch those 'extra' fields to get them parsed into Kibana.

Comment: What do you mean for 'extra'? You are looking for some additional fields at the end of the regular Django log? I never worked with that, so I don't know how is going to be generated the string from your example, but adding a regex wont help? Something like `grok { match => ["message",  %{DJANGO_LOG} %{GREEDYDATA:new_field_1}" ]  }`

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a 'quick' way to parse all different logs at once, you have to create different patterns. What you can do is optimize your regexs adding complexity.

Comment: Okay I see, so I have to write a different filter with each type of log?
What would be the grok entry for the example I wrote?

Comment: Not exactly. In a single grok filter you can put multiple patterns: the first matching is the one extracted. If you put an example string resulting from that command, I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Django pattern provided here [Django logging format for Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408268/django-logging-format-for-logstash) and add some additional info, watching the log in string format resulting from your command.

If you have for example three possible log format, the grok filter will extract the fields from the first matching pattern. You can define different behaviours if any pattern is matching, but for this I suggest you to check the docs.

```
filter {
 if [type] == "django" {
    grok {
         match => {
           "message" => [
             "%{DJANGO_LOG}",
             "%{DJANGO_LOG} %{GREEDYDATA:extra_1} %{IP:extra_2}",
             "%{DJANGO_LOG} %{GREEDYDATA:extra_1} %{IP:extra_2} abc %{GREEDYDATA:extra_3}",
           ]
         }
         patterns_dir => ["/opt/logstash/patterns", "/opt/logstash/extra_patterns"]
    }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS"]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
 }
```

}

Where in your file `/opt/logstash/patterns` or `/opt/logstash/extra_patterns` you have to put your custom patterns, referring to the previous link:

```
DJANGO_LOGLEVEL (DEBUG|INFO|ERROR|WARNING|CRITICAL)
DJANGO_LOG %{DJANGO_LOGLEVEL:log_level}\s+%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp}\s+%{TZ:log_tz}\s+%{NOTSPACE:logger}\s+%{WORD:module}\s+%{POSINT:proc_id}\s+%{GREEDYDATA:content}
```

If you have your specific string to parse (put an example string please, no functions!), I can help you, just post it in the comments.

Pro tip: if you need some help building custom regex using grok, check [this link](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com)

Comment: Thanks for helping! Kibana refreshed the fields somehow and I now have the 'fields' splitted in individual fields. I still can't aggregate them or anything.
Here's a message example I'm getting into Kibana : https://pastebin.com/9rZUxaqc

How would I do to count how many messages are concerning a specific "platform" for example?

Comment: I'm glad I helped you! You can use the `Visualize` feature on Kibana to count specific elements. Select `Area Chart` and your index, then on `buckets` select `X-Axis type`, then `Aggregation -> Terms`, you select your `Field` (let's say platform) and press the play button in the top right side, as long as the default metric (aka `Order by`) is `Count`. If any result is returned, please check the considered time range in the top right of the GUI, you may want to extend it (for example to `Last 5 years`). This 'mini guide' is referred to Kibana 5.2.2.

Comment: Thanks, this is working! Should I create another index for other log types?

Comment: Great, you are welcome! :) Creating a separate index for each log is suggested if they have totally different semantic meaning (for example separating proxy from portal or email). Additionally, if you have lot of data for a single index you should probably think about creating multiple indexes for each log type (maybe separating for month, like `django-2017-06`). This depends strictly on your resources, how many nodes you have, and how many logs you receive per timeframe (500 milions log each day? 1000 logs each month?)

Comment: So my application is just raising logs from a celery application witch fetches prices and some values from a remote account. Each worker is raising logs from python-logstash but with different values each time (eg. balance for account for a certain worker with platform: string, currency: string, amount: float and another one with totally different values). I don't feel like this would be a good idea to mix those different fields and meanings under the same index right?

Comment: Again, this depends strictly on your choices and how you are going to use your data. If you have different platforms, currencies and amounts but the semantics is defined inside the log, why don't keep them together? If you can't separate logs once loaded (ie the same currency refers to two separated products, for example), keep them separated. But this is an architectural problem, depends on the whole environment and I can't tell you, there isn't a best practice for this.